# Feature Request: Searchkit - new display format for representing diagrams

Tags: searchkit, display, formbuilder, chart

**SearchKit** and **Formbuilder** are impressively good at linking data from different entities and displaying them together. However, the **display** is so far limited to the view **as table, list or grid**.
How would it be if there were additional (possibly also very simple) displays as **diagrams** (e.g. pie chart, bar chart, line chart). I imagine that one adds a diagram as a display and must indicate in this which column from the Composed Search is to be represented on the X- and Y-axis.
As a display libraries could possibly something like [threejs](https://threejs.org) probably rather even [dc-js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js) be useful.
Possibly one can build there even on the work of [civisualize](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisualize-missing-data-visualization-extension). These allow impressive visualizations, but for the adjustment a visualization must be coded in each case.
This approach with Searchkit & Formbuilder should be configurable (even if with reduced functionality) on the surface.

Comment: Hi @tycho - this would be useful but may get lost here.  I'd suggest creating a request at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues